# NULL list of documents after querying Firestore with each element of given List

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am creating a flutter application where I wanted to search a list of usernames in firestore.

I am trying to make a query request with each element of a given list in Firebase Firestore but getting a null list of documents even when given elements of the list are correct.

```
static void searchUsersWithPhone(List<String> name) { // here name list is ['xyz', 'abc']
List email;
name.forEach((element) async {
  final snapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').where('name', isEqualTo: element).get();
  print(snapshot.docs); // giving null list
});
```

}

Firestore format:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Updated answer:*** The `forEach()` method expects a synchronous callback, so you can't await calls inside it, **use a `For` Loop instead .**

Comment: Hey Rishi, my answer was to clarify that you are querying correctly, your question doesn't have enough information to debug, so please provide the results you got in that case to be able to help. Also try querying without the .where part to see if the query is getting any results at all. @RishiMalgwa

Comment: The strings form 'name' list are correct. Query (.where ) is not working with foreach loop. When i am using only one string without list then i am getting correct results.

Comment: I am getting null list of documents. Just again read question and code i have mentioned about null list.

Comment: @RishiMalgwa Let me know if this works now with the For loop, would appreciate the solution tick if it did :)